# Connect to junos on VirtualBox (using netconf protocol)

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, juniper-network-connect, ietf-netconf

I have done everything like in [this](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/topic-map/netconf-ssh-connection.html#task-netconf-service-over-ssh-enabling) article. There is an account (with super-user privileges), password, `set netconf ssh` and `set ssh` commands issued along with an ip address (for `em0` `192.168.56.150/24`). My host OS (windows 8.1) for `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network` has `192.168.56.101`. I have downloaded and "ready to run" [Netconf java toolkit](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.3/information-products/pathway-pages/netconf-java-toolkit/netconf-java-toolkit.html) (by juniper group). How can I connect to junos instance from java toolkit ? (how to set adressess between host os and juniper os running inside virtualbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On junos box:

```
config# set system services netconf ssh

config# commit
```

Use the below link to create simple java program on host and the program:

[Link](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.3/topics/topic-map/netconf-java-toolkit-program-files-creating-and-executing.html)

Device device = new Device("junos-box-ip-address", "username-junos", "password-junos", null);